# I cannot see a page in my spring boot vaadin flow application

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin-flow

While my spring boot vaadin flow application compiles successfully I cannot see any page in browser. When I run http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello I just see :

> > Could not navigate to 'hello' Available routes: This detailed message is only shown when running in development mode.

Can you help me? I suspect it is an annotation issue. Bellow I show the annotation of 3 classes:

```
    @Theme(themeClass = Lumo.class)
@CssImport("./styles/select-lumo-bright.css")
@SpringBootApplication

public class PayrollApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements AppShellConfigurator
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PayrollApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

```
    @Component()
@ComponentScan("com.tool.jdbc")
@UIScope 
@Route(value = "hello", layout = MainView.class)
public class PanelMain extends Div implements Constants,AfterNavigationObserver {
```

---

```
public class MainView extends AppLayout implements Constants{
```

---

thank you

Comment: What is Constants?

Comment: @ComponentScan("com.tool.jdbc") should be on the PayrollApplicaion

Comment: @Component() is superfluous on a Route class

Comment: thannk you @SimonMartinelli. Constants is a class containing constant values

Comment: What is your package structure like (especially regarding PayrollApplication and PanelMain)?